# Customizar UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, objective-c

É possível trocar o elemento [image]
<sub>(fonte: [iab.net](https://www.iab.net/extra/adquickref/spinnerLarge.gif))</sub>   de um `UIActivityIndicatorView` por um gif específico? Como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomendo utilizar o [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)
Essa biblioteca tem vários tipos de indicadores de progresso já implementados e também permite definir uma view customizada, através da propriedade `customView`. Por exemplo, assumindo que sua view customizada se chama `customImageView`, o código ficaria parecido com isso:

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.customView = customImageView;
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
[HUD show:YES];
```

Para criar o gif, sugiro utilizar essa categoria: https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif
Também é possível utilizar a propriedade `animationImages`de UIImageView, atribuindo um array de objetos `UIImage`:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
imageView.animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_01.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_02.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_03.png"]];
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[imageView startAnimating];
```